# fringes on sephardic tiztzit

Tags: minhag, tzitzis, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi

I saw many Ashkenazim have fringes on wool Tzitzit like on a Tallit. I don't see Sephardim having it on tzitzit though. Is this an Ashkenazi Minhag? Basically, fringes look like this
[image: :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the edge of the tallis people a lot of the times will leave the warp threads without the weft and tie it so that it does not unravel when washed. (see Mishna Berura 11:54). It is probably done today for that reason and also adornment, and I don't see anything wrong with a Sefardic person wearing tzitzis with these knots on the side. In my experience, basically all talleisim (Sefardic or not) have them on the side. As for tallis kattan, these knots are basically only made on woolen garments.

Comment: Seeker, this clears up the use of the fringes on the talit Gadol. But in terms of talit kattan- most Sephardic poskim (and plenty of Ashkenazi ones as well) hold that a tallit kattan- should/must be made of wool

Comment: nice answer i just want more sources

Comment: also the mishna berura is how ashkenazim usually hold like.

Comment: @yehoshuanisanov true that mishna berura is ashkenizic minhagim, however, it was just stating the function of the knots - it wasn't saying it is a halacha to have them, therefore i think it answers the question.